При запуске файла docker в Teamcity он зависает в fetch apk
У меня есть docker в моем проекте, который выглядит следующим образом
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache freetype fontconfig ttf-dejavu

WORKDIR /app


COPY target/Authentication_Service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp.jar


EXPOSE 8086


ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "myapp.jar"]

и teamcity запускает этот docker, используя команды на этапе сборки (Build Steps)
docker stop mc-auth-conteiner 2>/dev/null || true
docker rm mc-auth-conteiner
docker build -t mc-auth .
docker run -d --name mc-auth-conteiner --network deploy_network -p 8086:8086 mc-auth

и как только teamcity запускает docker, он зависает при извлечении fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
Что я действительно попробовал это добавить --mtu=1300 в команды, которые использует teamcity, как показано ниже
docker stop mc-auth-conteiner 2>/dev/null || true
docker rm mc-auth-conteiner
docker build -t mc-auth .
docker run -d --name mc-auth-conteiner --network deploy_network --mtu=1300 -p 8086:8086 mc-auth

Этот подход также не помог, чего мне здесь не хватает, заранее благодарю.

Похоже не доступны сервера обновлений. Можно попробовать заставить apk показывать больше логов.

Исправился. Просто было надо добавлять ----network host таким образом
docker build --network host -t mc-auth .

